# insert batch in codeigniter, if no duplicates in specific column

Tags: php, sql-server, codeigniter-3, bulkinsert

I have a table in my database. The table structure is as follows

[image]

I need to insert data to this table as a batch, but avoid duplicate entry (here duplicate means same **combination of intCampaignID and intMobileNumber**).

The following is the insert function in my model

```
function addToCampaign($data){
    $voiceengine = $this->load->database('voiceengine', TRUE);
    $scheduleData = array();

    $mobiles = explode(',', $data['destinations']); 
    $mobilesData = array();
    foreach($mobiles as $mobile){    
        if (trim(strlen($mobile)) > 10)
            $mobile = substr(trim($mobile), -10); 
        else
            $mobile = trim($mobile);
        if(!in_array($mobile, $mobilesData)){
            array_push($mobilesData, $mobile);
        }  

    }

    foreach($mobilesData as $mobile){            

        $campaignData = array(
            'intCampaignID' => $data['campaign'],
            'intMobileNumber' => $mobile);                    

        array_push($scheduleData, $campaignData);
    } 
    $voiceengine->insert_batch('Voice.CampaignNumbers', $scheduleData);
}
```

I am not sure how to do this. I searched for a solution, but all the solutions are avoiding duplicates based on key. But these fields are not key fields and I have no privilege to change the structure. Someone please help me to do this

**UPDATE**
I have updated my function in model

```
function addToCampaign($data){
    $voiceengine = $this->load->database('voiceengine', TRUE);
    $scheduleData = array();

    $mobiles = explode(',', $data['destinations']); 
    $mobilesData = array();
    foreach($mobiles as $mobile){    
        if (trim(strlen($mobile)) > 10)
            $mobile = substr(trim($mobile), -10); 
        else
            $mobile = trim($mobile);
        if(!in_array($mobile, $mobilesData)){
            array_push($mobilesData, $mobile);
        }  

    }

    foreach($mobilesData as $mobile){ 
        $voiceengine->where('intCampaignID', $data['campaign']); 
        $voiceengine->where('intMobileNumber', $mobile);  
        $count = $voiceengine->count_all_results('Voice.CampaignNumbers');    // need a simple method  
        if($count <= 0)   {    

            $campaignData = array(
                'intCampaignID' => $data['campaign'],
                'intMobileNumber' => $mobile);                    

            array_push($scheduleData, $campaignData);
        }
    } 
    $voiceengine->insert_batch('Voice.CampaignNumbers', $scheduleData);
}
```

The updated function will work. But I am looking for a simple solution

Answer (score 2):

Before inserting remove the duplicate values :

`$scheduleData = array_map("unserialize", array_unique(array_map("serialize", $scheduleData)));`

and then run the `insert_batch` function

Comment: Clever one-liner. A lot more straight-forward than it appears.

Comment: @prakash the above code is to create unique array right?

Comment: @geeth : Yes it should be. please verify as i didn't check your code.

Comment: @prakashtank My array is already unique. But this array may contain data which is already in the table. Actually i need avoid this duplication at the time of insertion to table. something like `$sql = $this->db->insert_string('YourTable', $data) . ' ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE duplicate=duplicate+1';`

Comment: I got this problem too, do you have the solution?